# Cannot find a Player for :file:/C:/Users/ram/Desktop/desktop/Ringtones/02 - Diamond Girl.wmv

Tags: java, jmf

Points that I need to get clarified

**1.** Should I need to install `JMF` Studio to run video in `java` ???
**2.** post installation should I need to import some packages to run different file    format

Problem:
After installing `JMF` studio my program is unable to run video and audio its is picking up the path of the file and throughing me Cannot find a Player for your file

```
public class MediaTest
{

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {

      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();


      int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( null );

      if ( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )  
      {
         URL mediaURL = null;
          try
         {

            mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
         }  
         catch ( MalformedURLException malformedURLException )
         {
            System.err.println( "Could not create URL for the file" );
         }  

         if ( mediaURL != null ) 
         {
            JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame( "Media Tester" );
            mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

            MediaPanel mediaPanel = new MediaPanel( mediaURL );
            mediaTest.add(mediaPanel);
            mediaTest.setSize( 300, 300 );
            mediaTest.setVisible( true );
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually, `.www` files aren't played by media players.

Comment: its just an egg im using .wmv in real

Comment: JMF does not support WMV.  See the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) page for formats that it *might support.*

Comment: please let me know which format it will support and should i instal JMF studio ??